# JS / jQUERY - To make variable which contains API key invisible in the JS code

Tags: javascript, api, encryption

Is it possible to hide api key variable in JS code, hide it somehow or or encrypt it in the source code? Thanks.

Comment: Have a server in the middle that runs a server side language. NodeJS or PHP are the two easiest options.

Comment: how could that be done in PHP?

Comment: Get the PHP to listen to POSTS from Javascript, and then use something like cURL to foward the message with your API key.

Comment: ok, let me invesigate this. Do you have maybe some usful link that could help me achiving this? Thanks for now.

Comment: Have a look at this https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post this example is a server forwarding the requests.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

Javascript code is client-side.  Client-side means out of your control.

You can obfuscate, encode, encrypt as much as you want, but the browser will always have access to this information if it is used client-side.